# Custom plugin not appearing

Tags: plugin-development, customization, block-editor

I am learning how to develop a plugin for wordpress. I am running into some issue. The plugin that I am developing is a custom block. I am able to successfully activate the plugin but when I go to my block editor, the custom block is not there. Could I have some one take a look at what I have to make sure there are no mistakes?

PHP File:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin name: Animation fade custom block
 * Descritption: Plugin used to implement fade-in/out effects
 */

 function midstory_fade_animation_script_register()
 {
    // Script name, script location, related js name, array of dependecies, Word press refresh?, in footer boolean
    wp_enqueue_script('midstory-animation-fade-block', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'midstory_animation_fade.js', array('wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor'), true, false);
 }

 add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'midstory_fade_animation_script_register');

?>
```

Javascript:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('midstory/custom-block',{
    title: 'Animation Fade Block',
    icon: 'hammer', // Go to https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#minus for dash icons
    category: 'design',
    attributes: {
        fadeInLength: {type: 'string'},
        fadeOutLength: {type: 'string'},
        Picture: {type: 'string'} // Location of Picture
    },
    edit: function(props){// All properties pulled from WP blocks
        return React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Fade In Time"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
          type: "text",
          value: props.attributes.fadeInLength,
          placeholder: "0"
        }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Fade out Time"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
          type: "text",
          value: props.attributes.fadeOutLength,
          placeholder: "0"
        }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Image"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
          type: "text",
          value: props.attributes.Picture,
          placeholder: "/example/location"
        }));
    },
    save:function(props){
        return null;
    }




})
```

Comment: In the browser's developer tools can you see your script loading? Is the URL correct? If so, are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few parameters need tweaking in `midstory_fade_animation_script_register()`:

```
function midstory_fade_animation_script_register() {
    // Handle, script location, dependecies, version, in footer boolean
    wp_enqueue_script( 'midstory-animation-fade-block', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/midstory_animation_fade.js', array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor' ), '1.0.1', false );
}
```

- The script location needs a slash between the plugin folder and the filename.
- What you were calling "WordPress refresh?" is for a version number.

That will get your block showing up as an option to add in the Editor. Beyond that, you should look into [wordpress/element](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-element/) rather than calling React directly as WordPress has built wrappers around its functionality.

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer. Thank you so much. It is now appearing in the editor as intended! I would upvote but my rep is too low